# Sum array values based on conditions in other arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code that sums the values in `wgt_dif` (a `numpy` array) if certain conditions in two other `numpy` arrays are met. It is basically the equivalent of a SUMIFS function in Excel.

```
sum_4s = 0

for i in range(len(pntl)):
    if pntl[i] == 4 and adj_wgt[i] != max_wgt:
        sum_4s += wgt_dif[i]
```

I'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to write this. It works fine, but I'm new to Python and `numpy` and would like to expand my "vocabulary".

Comment: Tell us about the inputs, `pntl`, `adj_wgt` and `wgt_dif`.  Lists, arrays, dtype, shape, size, etc.

Comment: @hpaulj Each of pntl, adj_wgt, and wgt_dif are of type = numpy.ndarray, shape (40,), and dtype = float64.  Thank you for your thorough answer below and for introducing me to mask index arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make a test case:

```
In [59]: x = np.random.randint(0,10,10000)
In [60]: x.shape
Out[60]: (10000,)
```

(I thought test cases like this were required on Code Review.  We like to have then on SO, and CR is supposed to be stricter about code completeness.)

Your code as a function:

```
def foo(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif):
    sum_4s = 0
    for i in range(len(pntl)):
        if pntl[i] == 4 and adj_wgt[i] != 10:
           sum_4s += wgt_dif[i]
    return sum_4s
```

Test it with lists:

```
In [61]: pntl = adj_wgt = wgt_dif = x.tolist() # test list versions

In [63]: foo(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif)
Out[63]: 4104
In [64]: timeit foo(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop
```

Same test with array inputs is slower (lesson - if you must loop, lists are usually better):

```
In [65]: timeit foo(x,x,x)
The slowest run took 5.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 3.97 ms per loop
```

The suggested list comprehension is modestly faster

```
In [66]: sum([w for w, p, a in zip(wgt_dif, pntl, adj_wgt) if p == 4 and a != 10])
Out[66]: 4104
In [67]: timeit sum([w for w, p, a in zip(wgt_dif, pntl, adj_wgt) if p == 4 and a != 10])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop
```

`foo` could have been written with `zip` instead of the indexed iteration. (todo - time that).

But since you say these are arrays, let's try a numpy version:

```
def foon(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif):
    # array version
    mask = (pntl==4) & (adj_wgt != 10)
    return wgt_dif[mask].sum()

In [69]: foon(x,x,x)
Out[69]: 4104
In [70]: timeit foon(x,x,x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 µs per loop
```

This is an order of magnitude faster.  So if you already have arrays, try to work with them directly, without iteration.

---

```
def foo2(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif):
    sum_4s = 0
    for w, p, a in zip(wgt_dif, pntl, adj_wgt):
        if p == 4 and a != 10:
           sum_4s += w
    return sum_4s
In [77]: foo2(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif)
Out[77]: 4104
In [78]: timeit foo2(pntl, adj_wgt, wgt_dif)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 ms per loop
```

So it's the `zip` that speeds up your original code, not the list comprehension.

Comment: For the OP: the important bit in this answer is the use of a [mask index array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays): `wgt_dif[(pntl == 4) & (adj_wgt != 10)].sum()`

Answer (score 2):

```
sum([w for w, p, a in zip(wgt_dif, pntl, adj_wgt) if p == 4 and a != max_wgt])
```

---

Explanation:

```
zip(a, b, c)
```

creates the list of triplets of corresponding values from the lists `a`, `b`, `c` - something as

```
[(a[0], b[0], c[0]), (a[1], b[1], c[1]), (a[2], b[2], c[2]), ...]
```

so the part

```
for w, p, a in zip(wgt_dif, pntl, adj_wgt)
```

loops over this triples, associating th 1<sup>st</sup> item to `w`, 2<sup>nd</sup> to `p`, and 3<sup>rd</sup> to `a`.

Comment: And how does this compare to the OP's `for loop` version?  Other than being a one liner, it doesn't look any simpler or clearer.  Is it faster?

Comment: @hpaulj - "I'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to write this" was the only OP question. Is something bad with the fact that I answered it? BTW, in my answer IS something new (`sum()`) and it **is** both simpler and cleaner - and I'm sure it *will be for you, too* sometime in future.

Comment: I showed in my answer that your approach provides a modest speed increase, mainly from the use of `zip`.  In simple cases list comprehensions also improve speed.  But as they get more complex they lose both the speed and clarity advantage.

Comment: @hpaulj - Your answer is really very nice one - in spite of you didn't answer the OP question, I'm sorry. It was not about the speed. My list comprehension is not a complex one, is it?